# "Pick 'n' mix" structs?

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have structs A, B and C which all have different properties in them. Is it possible to make a "pick 'n' mix struct" via multiple inheritance and if so how do you later access a property from one of the inherited variables from the "pick 'n' mix structs"? e.g.:

```
struct A {int a1,a2};
struct B {int b1,b2};
struct C {int c1,c2};
struct PickNMix:A,B {int p1};
PickNMix pnm;
int x=pnm.a2 //<--just an educated guess of the syntax but not sure at all about it...if it works it should return NULL
```

Also, is there a better/more efficient way of doing this sort of thing? If so, please explain.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: You've defined a bunch of types. You haven't created any objects of those types. Once you have an object, as in `PickNMix obj;`, then you can indeed access its members, as in `obj.a2`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik oops mistake. I've corrected it now.

Comment: It works. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin for doing this with full blown classes.